# The output of PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, fileoutputstream

I am using PHPExcel to output excel file to users. I have pasted some code in the following.

```
 public function outPut($name=null)
    {
        if(is_null($name)) $name = $this->setName();

        ob_end_clean();
        header("Content-Type:application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type:application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type:application/download");
        header('Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="'.$name.'.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
        $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->phpExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

    }
```

The problem is the file downloaded from browser id broken and i can't open it.
But if i add exit in the end，everything is well

```
public function outPut($name=null)
    {
        if(is_null($name)) $name = $this->setName();

        ob_end_clean();
        header("Content-Type:application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type:application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type:application/download");
        header('Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="'.$name.'.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
        $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->phpExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        exit;   // works well
    }
```

I guess it is something about output buffering,so could anyone give me the direction to find the reason.

Comment: you probably have additional output from your script which you shouldent

Comment: The downloaded file size is smaller after i add 'exit' in my code. But i do not manually output anything in my code.

Comment: exactly you have more ouput, its going in to the file making it invalid

Comment: I have the direction. But i do not output anything after that. So it is possibile that the framework output some date to browser automatically?

Comment: That probably depends on the framework you're using. Most MVC frameworks nowadays have some kind of Response object that the controller returns.

Comment: yes its possible, we dont know what framework you are using, you can see the output in the file, just open it with a text editor.